# sort arrays of double in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, double

if I have an array

```
double i[5] = {1.023, 1.22, 1.56, 2, 5, 3.331};
```

how do i sort the values so that they look like this:

```
double i[5] = {1.023, 1.22, 1.56, 2, 3.331, 5};
```

i've tried qsort() with no luck, after trying some examples, i came up with:

```
qsort(i, 5, sizeof(double), sort);

int sort(const void *x, const void *y)
{
return (*(double*)x - *(double*)y);
}
```

with => <strike>error: incompatible type for argument 1</strike>
not sorting the array.....

Comment: "incompatible type for argument 1" are you sure you're compiling this as C, and not C++? If you really have to compile it as C++, then cast it to (void *).

Comment: Just for clarity, Your comparison routine should be called something like `compare`, not `sort`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first argument to `qsort` is the pointer to the start of the array to be sorted. Instead of

```
qsort(i[5], 5, sizeof(double), sort);
```

it should read

```
qsort(i, 5, sizeof(double), sort);
```

Some further observations:

1. The length of `i`'s initializer is incorrect (`i` has five elements, yet the initializer has six).
2. Hard-coding the 5 into the `qsort` call is asking for trouble later on.
3. The name "`i`" is most commonly used for loop counters and the like.
4. Calling the comparison function `sort` is confusing.
5. Your comparison function is wrong. Consider how it would compare the numbers `1.1` and `1.2`. Also think about what would happen if the difference between the two values doesn't fit in an `int`.

I would rewrite your entire example like so:

```
double arr[] = {1.023, 1.22, 1.56, 2, 5, 3.331};

int cmp(const void *x, const void *y)
{
  double xx = *(double*)x, yy = *(double*)y;
  if (xx < yy) return -1;
  if (xx > yy) return  1;
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  qsort(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), sizeof(arr[0]), cmp);
}
```

Note that the above comparison function still doesn't correctly handle NaNs; I leave it as an exercise for the reader to fix that.

Comment: opps , typo, i updated the question, but now, it's not returning sorted array:(

Comment: @Tom91136: Your `sort` function is wrong. See the updated answer.

Comment: thanks! i was so stupid, that sort function was originally used somewhere in my code to sort int arrays...

Comment: @Tom91136: Even for int arrays, that comparison function (*please* don't call it `sort`) won't always work.  The difference between to `int` values won't necessarily fit in an `int`; for example, `INT_MAX - INT_MIN` will overflow.  A trick I've seen is `return (xx > yy) - (xx < yy);`.